# MAC VSCode remote ssh extension failed to connect to Linux server

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, ssh

I am trying to use VSCode remote ssh extension to access a folder on my school machine. I think initially the connection was established since it prompted me to enter the password. But then the window is stuck, and here is the output:

```
  [16:27:58.275] > Warning: no access to tty (Inappropriate ioctl for device).
    > Thus no job control in this shell.
    [16:27:58.340] > ready: 4b31ee9ef295
    [16:27:58.410] > Linux 4.19.0-13-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.160-2 (2020-11-28)
    [16:27:58.410] Platform: linux
    [16:27:58.552] stderr> bash: line 360: syntax error near unexpected token `('
    [16:27:58.552] stderr> bash: line 360: `echo "* as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057)"'
    [16:27:58.552] stderr> function: Command not found.
    [16:27:58.552] stderr> Bad : modifier in $ '-'.
    [16:27:58.553] > 4b31ee9ef295: running
    > *
    >  
    [16:27:58.553] stderr> VSCH_LOGFILE: Undefined variable.
    [16:27:58.553] stderr> LISTENING_ON=: Command not found.
    [16:27:58.554] stderr> VSCH_LOGFILE: Undefined variable.
    [16:27:58.554] stderr> WEBUITOKEN=: Command not found.
    [16:27:58.554] stderr> LISTENING_ON: Undefined variable.
```

The problem should not be on my school's server side because I used the ssh command in zsh and it successfully connects. So can anyone tell me where the problem is? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 8):

Open command palette, run "Remote-SSH: Settings", then config "Remote.SSH: Remote Server Listen On Socket" to true. This did the trick for me.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried turning it off and it doesn't even prompt me for the password and just directly fails.